# Rotations with QQuaternion and QSlider

Tags: qt, rotation, quaternions, qslider

I have implemented an Objectrotation with QQuaternion and QPushButton.
As long as the plus_x_button is pushed the slot rotate_plus_x() is activated.
Respectively for minus_x.

```
void OpenGLScene::rotate_plus_x()
{
  OpenGLScene::anglex = 2;
  test->rotation *= QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),OpenGLScene::anglex);
  update();
}

void OpenGLScene::rotate_minus_x()
{
  OpenGLScene::anglex = -2;
  test->rotation *= QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),OpenGLScene::anglex);
  update();
}
void OpenGLScene::rotate_plus_y(){...}
void OpenGLScene::rotate_minus_y(){...}

void OpenGLScene::rotate_plus_z(){...}
void OpenGLScene::rotate_minus_z(){...}
```

Now I would like to realize the functionality with a Qslider instead of the QPushButton.
With a range between -180° and 180°
But then I have the problem that I get weird outcomes because the value of the Qslider is changed and the QQuaternion expexts a nonchangeble angle.
Have you an idea how to achieve that? I have tried it with if-statements. 
Something like:

```
if(slidervalue<0){
OpenGLScene::anglex = -2;
test->rotation *= QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),OpenGLScene::anglex);}
else{
OpenGLScene::anglex = 2;
test->rotation *= QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),OpenGLScene::anglex);}
```

Unfortunately its not working. Do you have an idea, how to achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to get what you're looking for, you should assign rather than multiply.

That is, if you slider is set to have values from -179 to +180 degrees, then you can just say:

```
OpenGLScene::anglex = slidervalue;
test->rotation = QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),OpenGLScene::anglex);
```

Note that I'm using **=** instead of `*=`.  That makes that the slider behave intuitively.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem